Ingeniería inversa APK
Estoy investigando sobre ingeniería inversa y he utilizado enjarify para obtener el .jar y luego luyten para descompilar. Se que al descompilar puede haber fallos y no puedo obtener el código original pero no entiendo como traducirlo, por ejemplo: k$b. He intentado buscar información al respecto y no encuentro nada que me  ayude. (Estoy en 1o de ingeniería informática y no tengo mucha idea).
Este es el código de una de las clases:
package q2;

import android.graphics.*;
import java.util.*;

public final class k
{
    public float a;
    public float b;
    public float c;
    public float d;
    public float e;
    public float f;
    public final ArrayList g;
    public final ArrayList h;
    
    public k() {
        this.g = new ArrayList();
        this.h = new ArrayList();
        this.f(0.0f, 270.0f, 0.0f);
    }
    
    public final void a(float n, final float n2, float c, float d, float f, float g) {
        final k$d k$d = new k$d(n, n2, c, d);
        k$d.f = f;
        k$d.g = g;
        this.g.add(k$d);
        final k$b k$b = new k$b(k$d);
        final float n3 = f + g;
        boolean b;
        if (g < 0.0f) {
            b = true;
            g = Float.MIN_VALUE;
        }
        else {
            b = false;
            g = 0.0f;
        }
        final float n4 = 360.0f;
        final float n5 = 180.0f;
        if (b) {
            f = (f + n5) % n4;
        }
        float e;
        if (b) {
            e = (n5 + n3) % n4;
        }
        else {
            e = n3;
        }
        this.b(f);
        this.h.add(k$b);
        this.e = e;
        f = n + c;
        g = 0.5f;
        f *= g;
        c -= n;
        n = 2.0f;
        c /= n;
        final double n6 = n3;
        c = c * (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(n6)) + f;
        this.c = c;
        c = (n2 + d) * g;
        d = (d - n2) / n;
        n = (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(n6));
        d = d * n + c;
        this.d = d;
    }
    
    public final void b(final float e) {
        final float e2 = this.e;
        if (e2 == e) {
            return;
        }
        final float n = e - e2;
        final float n2 = 360.0f;
        final float g = (n + n2) % n2;
        if (g > 180.0f) {
            return;
        }
        final float c = this.c;
        final float d = this.d;
        final k$d k$d = new k$d(c, d, c, d);
        k$d.f = this.e;
        k$d.g = g;
        this.h.add(new k$b(k$d));
        this.e = e;
    }
    
    public final void c(final Matrix matrix, final Path path) {
        for (int size = this.g.size(), i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            ((k$f)this.g.get(i)).a(matrix, path);
        }
    }
    
    public final k$g d(final Matrix matrix) {
        this.b(this.f);
        return new k$a(new ArrayList(this.h), new Matrix(matrix));
    }
    
    public final void e(final float n, final float n2) {
        final k$e k$e = new k$e();
        k$e.b = n;
        k$e.c = n2;
        this.g.add(k$e);
        final k$c k$c = new k$c(k$e, this.c, this.d);
        final float b = k$c.b();
        final float n3 = 270.0f;
        final float n4 = b + n3;
        final float e = k$c.b() + n3;
        this.b(n4);
        this.h.add(k$c);
        this.e = e;
        this.c = n;
        this.d = n2;
    }
    
    public final void f(final float n, float n2, final float n3) {
        this.a = 0.0f;
        this.b = n;
        this.c = 0.0f;
        this.d = n;
        this.e = n2;
        n2 = (n2 + n3) % 360.0f;
        this.f = n2;
        this.g.clear();
        this.h.clear();
    }
}

Me gustaría saber como interpretar esto y entender cómo funciona. Gracias.

Las letras que ves en el código obtenido por ingeniería inversa son a partir de la previa ofuscación del código, en el caso de por ejemplo: k$b
k: es el nombre de la clase.
b: es el nombre del método.
En el caso de los parámetros de los métodos, por ejemplo:
 public final void a(float n, final float n2, float c, float d, float f, float g) {

Son nombre de variables n, n2, c, d, f y g.
Lo que tienes que realizar es renombrar las clases, métodos  y variables con nombres más descriptivos, esto para que empieces a obtener el código original.
public final class SegmentoArco
{
    ...
    ...   
    public SegmentoArco() {
       ...
       ...
    }
    
    public final void agregaSegmento(float n, final float n2, float c, float d, float f, float g) {
    ...
    ...

